# Combine/merge multiple maps into 1 map

Tags: dart

How can I combine/merge 2 or more maps in dart into 1 map?
for example I have something like:

```
 var firstMap = {"1":"2"};
 var secondMap = {"1":"2"};
 var thirdMap = {"1":"2"};
```

I want:

```
 var finalMap = {"1":"2", "1":"2", "1":"2"};
```

Comment: Your final map is not possible. Because your keys are idetical `"1"` and final result of `print({"1":"2", "1":"2", "1":"2"});` will be `{1: 2}`.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

you can use `addAll` method of `Map` object

```
var firstMap = {"1":"2"};
var secondMap = {"2":"3"};

var thirdMap = {};

thirdMap.addAll(firstMap);
thirdMap.addAll(secondMap);

print(thirdMap);
```

Or

```
var thirdMap = {}..addAll(firstMap)..addAll(secondMap);
```

## Update

Since dart sdk 2.3
You can use spread operator `...`

```dart
final firstMap = {"1":"2"};
final secondMap = {"2":"3"};

final thirdMap = {
   ...firstMap,
   ...secondMap,
};
```

Comment: Is there no way to merge all of them in one line though?

Comment: var finalMap = {}..addAll(firstMap)..addAll(secondMap)..addAll(thirdMap);

Comment: this doesn't work when combining maps with inner maps

Answer (score 15):

alternate syntax using `Map.addAll`, `Iterable.reduce` and [cascading operator](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-), for combining a lot of maps:

```
var combinedMap = mapList.reduce( (map1, map2) => map1..addAll(map2) );
```

live dartpad example 
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9cd116d07d2f45a9b890b4b1186dcc5e

Comment: Having the dartpad is awesome for this, shows pretty clearly how it works and I can play with the values. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
 var firstMap = {"1":"5"};
 var secondMap = {"1":"6"};
 var thirdMap = {"2":"7"};
 
 var finalMap = {...firstMap, ...secondMap, ...thirdMap};
 // finalMap: {"1":"6", "2":"7"};
```

Notice that key `"1"` with value `"5"` will be overwritten with `"6"`.

Comment: what if i want both value!

Comment: @ArpitJai Impossible. You need to find way around.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is using [`CombinedMapView`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/CombinedMapView-class.html) from `package:collection`:

```
new CombinedMapView([firstMap, secondMap])
```

It doesn't create a merged map, but creates a `Map` that is a *view* of both.

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: The link now works.

Answer (score 6):

I came up with a "single line" solution for an Iterable of Maps:

```
var finalMap = Map.fromEntries(mapList.expand((map) => map.entries));
```