# Flutter how to merge arrays

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching data like this

```
 Future<List> dosomestuff() async {

    http.Response res = await http.get(
      'http://retailapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/menu/2112',
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(res.body);
    print(map);
  }
```

Its showing data like this

```
 {
    "Categories": [{
            "ID": 1064,
            "Name": "Pizza",
            "Subcategories": [{
                    "ID": 87,
                    "CategoryID": 1064,
                    "CategoryName": "Pizza",
                    "Items": [{
                            "ID": 1195,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1196,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1197,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ID": 87,
                    "CategoryID": 1064,
                    "CategoryName": "Pizza",
                    "Items": [{
                            "ID": 1195,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1196,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1197,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": 1064,
            "Name": "Pizza",
            "Subcategories": [{
                "ID": 87,
                "CategoryID": 1064,
                "CategoryName": "Pizza",
                "Items": [{
                        "ID": 1195,
                        "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 1196,
                        "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 1197,
                        "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "ID": 1084,
            "Name": "beverages",
            "Description": null,
            "Image": null,
            "StatusID": 1,
            "LocationID": 2112,
            "Subcategories": []
        }
    ],
    "description": "Success",
    "status": 1
}
```

What i need to do know is show items of all arrays. Mean in above data there are 2 arrays in subcategories and in 1 array there are 3 items. I need to merge all items of array 1 and 2 so it can total 6.

```
Expecting output

                   { "Items": [
                        {
                            "ID": 1195,
                            "SubCategoryID": 87,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)",

                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1196,
                            "SubCategoryID": 87,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)",

                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1197,
                            "SubCategoryID": 87,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)",

                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1195,
                            "SubCategoryID": 87,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)",

                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1196,
                            "SubCategoryID": 87,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)",

                        },
                        {
                            "ID": 1197,
                            "SubCategoryID": 87,
                            "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)",

                        }
                    ]
                   }
```

Comment: You can extract subcategories from entity and combine it with each other.

Comment: Can you share the expected output with exact data and parameters ?(words are fine but exact output would be more precise)

Comment: @mozilla_firefox added expected outpu

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200659/11050506. You need get data from for loop than merge.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand what you want to do but you can try the addAll function

```
fetchedList = [a, b, 2, 3];
myList = [4, 5, c];
fetchedList.addAll(myList);

print(fetchedList); 
// [a, b, 2, 3, 4, 5, c]
```

Comment: But i dont have one list in data its have multiple categories and in categories there are multiple subcategories and then its are in sub categories. can you please see my data i have added in question i also have added expted result now ?

Comment: With forEach of the incoming data, you can add data from each element to different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

hope these steps help you:

1. Create a new empty map
2. Loop in your map **data['Categories']['Subcategories']**
3. Put each element in your new map

Answer (score 0):

You can use **forEach** to split the json data layer by layer

```
var items = {'Items':[]};
  
if(map['Categories'] != null){
  map['Categories'].forEach((category){
    if(category['Subcategories'] != null){
      category['Subcategories'].forEach((subcategory){
        items['Items'].addAll(subcategory['Items']);
      });
    }
  });   
}

print(items);
```

Comment: Hi Umaiz Khan, that message mean sometime the data get null when use the key.

Comment: Yes i see anything possibe if null so we can ignore it ?

Comment: I try your updated answer but dont know why its showing empty array in items {Items: []}

Comment: I tried to use a simply null safety method but seems the result is not as expected. I give you the traditional solution.

Comment: maybe you can check the key. I noticed I typo `Categories` to `Category`

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic data = {
  "Categories": [
    {
      "ID": 1064,
      "Name": "Pizza",
      "Subcategories": [
        {
          "ID": 87,
          "CategoryID": 1064,
          "CategoryName": "Pizza",
          "Items": [
            {"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"},
            {"ID": 1196, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"},
            {"ID": 1197, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": 87,
          "CategoryID": 1064,
          "CategoryName": "Pizza",
          "Items": [
            {"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"},
            {"ID": 1196, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"},
            {"ID": 1197, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": 1064,
      "Name": "Pizza",
      "Subcategories": [
        {
          "ID": 87,
          "CategoryID": 1064,
          "CategoryName": "Pizza",
          "Items": [
            {"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"},
            {"ID": 1196, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (M)"},
            {"ID": 1197, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (L)"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": 1084,
      "Name": "beverages",
      "Description": null,
      "Image": null,
      "StatusID": 1,
      "LocationID": 2112,
      "Subcategories": []
    },
    null
  ],
  "description": "Success",
  "status": 1
};
var items = List();
var categories = data["Categories"];
categories.forEach((element) {
  if (element == null) return;
  List subCategories = element['Subcategories'];
  subCategories.forEach((element) {
    items.add(element["Items"]);
  });
});
items = items.expand((element) => element).toList();
print(items);
```

Comment: in data there is one array which is null in categories you can see in my data. Thats why its showing error foreach is call on null

Comment: @UmaizKhan I updated the answer can u try like that?