# Flutter:How to merge two objects and sum the values of the same key?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, merge

map1 = { "a": 10, "b": 6 },
map2 = { "a": 10, "b": 6, "c": 7, "d": 8 };

Flutter:How to merge two objects and sum the values of the same key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do forEach on the longest map and check if the small map contains the key if it does then update the value with the sum or add the new.

```
  map2.forEach((key, value) {
    if (map1.containsKey(key)) {
      map1[key] = value + map1[key]!;
    } else {
      map1[key] = map2[key]!;
    }
  });
```

map1 will be the final result.

Answer (score -1):

So, if you want to combine/merge the two maps use this code [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200659/17170163):

```
final firstMap = {"1":"2"};
final secondMap = {"2":"3"};

final thirdMap = { // here simple adding element to map
...firstMap,
...secondMap,
};
```

but if you want to make sum and merge use this :

```
map2.forEach((k, v) {
if (map1.containsKey(k)) { // check if the map has more then 2 values as the 1st one
  map1[k] = v + map1[k]!; // if yes so make the some
} else {
  map1[k] = map2[k]!; // if no then add the values to map
}
});
```

as MEET Prajapati asnwer.

Comment: The first solution doesn't do the sum of the value if the keys are the same.

Comment: yes, as i said the first solution work in case the maps has same lenght

Comment: no, it won't mate! We want the result to be this  "{a: 20, b: 12, c: 7, d: 8}" and the first solution just merges the data without doing the sum of the values so it will give just "{a: 10, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8}" which is not what we want!