# Get data to API by Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I'm having trouble sending data from user-filled forms to save to API and since I'm new to writing apps in Flutter I don't understand many things.
My work process is We will get the value from the form Let's store it as a variable set like this, which will have many files that store the same data.

```
class _dataUserState extends State<dataUser> {
int selectedGenger = 0;
int age = 0;
int selectedStatus = 0;
int selectedChild = 0;
int childs = 0;
int workAgeYear = 0;
int workAgeMonth = 0;
int selectedEmployee = 0;
int selectedGroup = 0;
int selectedTypeA = 0;
int selectedTypeR = 0;
}
```

which these values ​​come from the radio button after collecting I'll check the data and send it to the class DataService

> ```
> void sendDataApi() {
>   bool isDataComplete = selectedGenger != 0 &&
>        age != 0 &&
>        selectedStatus != 0 &&
>        selectedChild != 0 &&
>        childs != 0 &&
>        workAgeYear != 0 &&
>        workAgeMonth != 0 &&
>        selectedEmployee != 0 &&
>        selectedGroup != 0 &&
>        selectedTypeA != 0 &&
>        selectedTypeR != 0;
> }
> ```

```
if (isDataComplete) {
  print('ข้อมูลพร้อมใช้');
  final dataService = DataService();
  dataService.selectedGenger = selectedGenger;
  dataService.age = age;
  dataService.selectedStatus = selectedStatus;
  dataService.selectedChild = selectedChild;
  dataService.childs = childs;
  dataService.workAgeYear = workAgeYear;
  dataService.workAgeMonth = workAgeMonth;
  dataService.selectedEmployee = selectedEmployee;
  dataService.selectedGroup = selectedGroup;
  dataService.selectedTypeA = selectedTypeA;
  dataService.selectedTypeR = selectedTypeR;

  // ส่งข้อมูลไป API
  dataService.sendDataToApi1();
} else {
  print('ข้อมูลยังมีค่าไม่ครบถ้วน');
  print('ตรวจสอบข้อมูลที่ยังไม่ครบ:');
  if (selectedGenger == 0) print('selectedGenger');
  if (age == 0) print('age');
  if (selectedStatus == 0) print('selectedStatus');
  if (selectedChild == 0) print('selectedChild');
  if (childs == 0) print('childs');
  if (workAgeYear == 0) print('workAgeYear');
  if (workAgeMonth == 0) print('workAgeMonth');
  if (selectedEmployee == 0) print('selectedEmployee');
  if (selectedGroup == 0) print('selectedGroup');
  if (selectedTypeA == 0) print('selectedTypeA');
  if (selectedTypeR == 0) print('selectedTypeR');
 }
}
```

which when the user selects radio It will come to sendToApi1() command.

```
Radio(
   value: sex.sexId,
   groupValue: selectedGenger,
   onChanged: (value) {
     setState(() {
      selectedGenger = value!;
      sendDataApi();
      print(selectedGenger);
   });
  },
),
```

Then, as per my understanding, the data goes to my `DataService` class and goes to sendToApi1(); mine is about this

> ```
> class DataService {
> int selectedGenger = 0;
> int age = 0;
> int selectedStatus = 0;
> int selectedChild = 0;
> int childs = 0;
> int workAgeYear = 0;
> int workAgeMonth = 0;
> int selectedEmployee = 0;
> int selectedGroup = 0;
> int selectedTypeA = 0;
> int selectedTypeR = 0;
> int n11 = 0;
> int n12 = 0;
> int n13 = 0;
> ```

> ```
> Future<void> sendDataToApi1() async {Map<String, dynamic> jsonData1 = {
> "selectedGender": selectedGenger,
> "age": age,
> "maritalId": selectedStatus,
> "haveChild": selectedChild,
> "numOfChild": childs,
> "workAgeYear": workAgeYear,
> "workAgeMonth": workAgeMonth,
> "level": selectedEmployee,
> "BUID": selectedGroup,
> "BID": selectedTypeA,
> "BUSGID": selectedTypeR,
> };
> print(jsonData1);
> }
> ```

> ```
> Future<void> sendDataToApi2() async {Map<String, dynamic> jsonData2 = {
> "n11": n11,
> "n12": n12,
> "n13": n13,
> };
> print(jsonData2);
> }
> ```

And I made a button for merging data on both my forms. Let's combine them into a single data set to be sent to an API in the future with this button.

> ```
> floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
> onPressed: navigateToNextTab,
> child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
> ),
> ```

which when the user presses this button it goes into command My `_navigateToNextTab()` like this

```
void _navigateToNextTab() async {
if (tabController.index tabController.length - 1) {
tabController.animateTo(tabController.index + 1);
} else {
DataService dataService = DataService();
await dataService.groupData();
}
}
```

My requirement is how to be able to combine the data from both forms that the user fills in. can be combined into a single set of data It's in JSON format.

Now I've tried several methods, await or others, but it always has a problem with the command. My `_navigateToNextTab()`
and I expect There will be an easier way, and not confusing for newbies like me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200560/combine-merge-multiple-maps-into-1-map